# named credential problem

Tags: namedcredentials

I am trying to implement named credential in my integration I am getting error below:

> The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the
>   required permissions, or the named credential "IntegLead" might not
>   exist.

Can Anyone help me to resolve this?

```
Label   IntegLead
Name    IntegLead
URL https://xxx.salesforce.com/  
Identity Type   Named Principal
Authentication Protocol Password Authentication
Username    xxxxx
password        xxxxx
Generate Authorization Header-enabled
Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header   
Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Body
```

Class:

```
public class SendLeadUsingRESTAPI {
   public class deserializeResponse
   {
      public String id;
      public String access_token;
   }
 public String ReturnAccessToken (SendLeadUsingRESTAPI leada)
   {
      Http h = new Http();
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      //req.setBody(reqbody);
      req.setMethod('GET');
      req.setEndpoint('callout:IntegLead');
      HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
      deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
      return resp1.access_token;
   }
   @future(callout=true)
   public static void callcreateAcc (List<Id> ids)
   {
     List<Lead> leads = [select lastname, company, status from lead where id in :ids];
     for (Lead ld :leads)
      ld.id = null;
      String jsonstr = (String)JSON.serialize(leads);
      SendLeadUsingRESTAPI leadb = new SendLeadUsingRESTAPI();
      String accessToken;
      accessToken = leadb.ReturnAccessToken(leadb);      
      if(accessToken != null){
      String endPoint = 'https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Lead/doPost';
      System.debug('hello'+jsonstr);
      Http h2 = new Http();
      HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
      req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
      req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
      req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
      req1.setBody(jsonstr);
      req1.setMethod('POST');
      req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
      HttpResponse res1 = h2.send(req1);
   }
}
}
```

Comment: For anyone else like me who isn't aware of the feature, here is a link to some [Named Credentials as Callout Endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm) documentation.

Comment: @KeithC any thought on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260242/connect-to-salesforce-production-rest-api-from-sandbox-using-named-credentials)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this part of a managed package.

If so you will need to prefix the named credential with `__` (two underscores) to indicate that you are using a named credential from the local namespace. [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BIAJIA4). You will need to skip this prefix in the packaging Dev org.

---

Another [source](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BXBdIAO) suggests that you need to include the package namespace after Winter '16.

> Before winter '16 you can use the Named Credential without the package name. From winter '16 you need to include the package name in the named credential.
>
> BEFORE Winter '16 : 'callout:namedCredential'
> AFTER Winter '16 : 'callout:packageName__namedCredential'

---

It is also worth checking that the Remote Site Settings will allow access to the URL from the named credential.

Comment: No its not part of managed package.I have used underscore.But I am getting error-The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential "__IntegLead" might not exist.

Comment: @VidhyasagaranMuralidharan Have you added the Remote Site Setting for the target URL as well?

Comment: There was problem in the remotesite setting.got it thanks

Comment: @DanielBallinger please could you help with [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260242/connect-to-salesforce-production-rest-api-from-sandbox-using-named-credentials)

Answer (score 0):

I Had same issue, from my understanding we dont have to add the remote site if we are using named credentials.
For me the error was fixed by not having a / at the end of the URL
[image]

Comment: I think back in the 2016 you had to add Remote Site Setting.