# Managed package post install script not making callout

Tags: apex, managed-package, callout

I've created a managed package to deploy some custom fields etc. I need a post install script to run and notify my server than the salesforce instance has installed the package. Here is my post install script:

```
public class PackagedInstallScript implements InstallHandler {
    public void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        String payload = getPayload(context);
        sendNotification(payload);
    }
    
    private String getPayload(InstallContext context) {
        String version;
        if (Test.isRunningTest())
            version = '1.0';
        else
            version = System.requestVersion().major() + '.' + System.requestVersion().minor();
        
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('Action', 'INSTALL_PACKAGE');
        gen.writeStringField('InstanceUrl', URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toString());
        gen.writeStringField('version', version);
        gen.writeEndObject();
        return gen.getAsString();
    }
    
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void sendNotification(String payload) {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('callout:my_external_app');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setBody(payload);
        
        if (!Test.isRunningTest())
            (new Http()).send(request);
    }
}
```

When I install the package on another salesforce instance, I expect to receive a notification in my external application, however I get nothing. I'm not sure where I can find the debug log for this script to see if it's thrown an error?

Also note I am referencing a named credential for the url for my external app which is part of the managed package. I wonder if my namespace prefix affects how I reference it?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the namespace (see [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/138127/2984) question, basically, `callout:myNameSpace__myCalloutName`).

Comment: OK so adding my namespace prefix to the callout as suggested worked. WITHOUT the namespace prefix I was getting an 'unauthorized endpoint' exception but I'm still able to do without remote site settings by using the namespace prefix. Thanks.

Comment: @jefferson Ah, good to know. I'll amend. Glad I was able to help!

Comment: @jefferson Just confirming. You are able to make a callout to an external endpoint with this? It is a bit concerning that the remote site setting isn't required.

Comment: Yes. If you remove the managed package from the situation, I'm able to reference/make callouts to named credentials without remote site settings. When distributing in a managed package, like I said the namespace prefix is required otherwise you get an unauthorized endpoint exception even though the `callout:named_cred` resolves to the endpoint correctly. Odd behavior but it is what it is.