# External Service in a Managed Package Doesn't Work in Subscriber Orgs

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, namedcredentials, external-services

I'm developing an api integration feature from Salesforce to an external web service in a managed package using External Service, Named Credential and Flow.

The feature works in a packaging org but doesn't work in a subscriber org. The error title is **"Callout failed: The callout couldn't access the endpoint."**

It looks like a namespace issue when a system refers to a named credential like this:
[named credential problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138127/named-credential-problem)

However, I can only choose a Named Credential declaratively in the External Service setting screen, so I have no idea if it refers namespace or not.

[image]

Do you guys have any idea to solve this issue or to know an External Service refers a namespace?

Additional Info:

My Schema

```
 {
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Slack + Salesforce",
    "description": "Instantly Send Messages to Slack from Salesforce",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "host": "hooks.slack.com",
  "schemes": [ "https" ],
  "paths": {
    "/workflows/myworkflowid": {
      "post": {
        "consumes": [ "application/json" ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "slackMessageRequest",
            "type": "object",
            "required": true,
            "schema" : {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/SlackMessageRequest"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Operation"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "SlackMessageRequest": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "organization":{
           "type": "string"
        },
       "error_name":{
           "type": "string"
        },
      "log_number":{
           "type": "string"
        },
      "record_url":{
           "type":"string"
        },
      "skill":{
         "type": "string"
       },
      "error_stack":{
         "type": "string"
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My named credential

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the `-meta.xml` files that make up your managed package metadata? You should, after all, be storing it all in version control for your package development. You can even try adding the namespace prefix to the reference to the named credential then push the metadata to a scratch org to see if the change is valid before trying to create a new package version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is already filed as a bug in Salesforce internally(#W-11058954). According to this, users are unable to make callout for Namespace'd managed package External Services.

When we make the External Service callout, we don't use the full NamedCredential name with the namespace. So it is unable to find the named credential causing the error.

There is no public-facing known issue for this bug at the moment. The ETA for the bug fix is Winter'23(Safe Harbour)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment!
That helps a lot. Then I will re-develop this feature by Apex. Thanks.

Comment: Will this be fixed with Winter '23?

Comment: @RobertSösemann I see that the scheduled build is 240 on the bug. The fix should be rolled out on all Winter'23 orgs already. Let me know if you observe anything odd. Thanks

Comment: I have no working example but I was planning to soon package an external Service. I had hoped you could quickly test if it has been solved or the original question owner @HirokiYuda.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Thank you for mentioning me, but I already implemented this feature by Apex and thus it's difficult to test the external service independently.

Comment: Hello @Swetha - Has this been fixed?

Comment: @JefersonChaves I see it fixed.

Comment: Thanks a million @Swetha. I wondered if this was related to a problem with External Authentication on Flows for Digital Experience Users.